# Job array Script

Tags: arrays, bash

I'm want to send a job array but still do not understand the whole process (Novice as i am). On the website, I found this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#$ -S /bin/bash
#$ -cwd
#$ -V
# The 'myprog' below is serial hence no '-pe' option needed

#$ -t 1-1000
# ...tell SGE that this is an array job, with "tasks" numbered from 1 
#    to 1000...

./myprog < data.$SGE_TASK_ID > results.$SGE_TASK_ID
```

Correct me if im wrong, the data has been indexed by the SGE system. But what is ",.myprog" means? is a different bash script that has the real task? Where is it save and how the job will locate the script?

Comment: Can you give a link to where you found this?  "on the website" doesn't really help, there are rather a lot to choose from.

Comment: My bad. it was from this link http://ri.itservices.manchester.ac.uk/csf/csf-user-documentation/sge-job-arrays/

Answer (score 1):

Generally `myprog` is just a generic name for an external program. In this case I would assume it is the program that does the work. It could be a bash script, but it could be written in any language, including C.

```
./myprog < data.$SGE_TASK_ID > results.$SGE_TASK_ID
```

The leading `./` indicates that the program (myprog) is found in the current directory.   You could replace the `.` with a real directory name if you wish.

`< data.$SGE_TASK_ID` indicates that "myprog's" input stream (known as `stdin`, or "standard input") comes from a file rather than the keyboard.  The filename is the word "data." followed by the value of the variable `SGE_TASK_ID`.  The leading `$` gives us the value of the variable.  From the code you show it is not clear where this variable comes from.*

`> results.$SGE_TASK_ID` is similar, except this is "myprog's" output stream (known as `stdout`, or "standard output") goes to a file rather than the terminal screen.

- Edit:  I find here: http://www3.imperial.ac.uk/bioinfsupport/help/cluster_usage/submitting_array_jobs  that the variable is set in the environment.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. i can seem to understand how SGE is use to index the inputs. Let say i have a directory "fasta" that contain all the fasta files that could be the input. according to the link you gave of which i already tried it before, nothing happened after i use "sed -n -e "$SGE_TASK_ID p" datafile"  for my fasta directory.